# TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not pygame.Rect

Tags: python, pygame

```
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width_display,height_display))
pygame.display.set_caption("Ballzy")


ballImg = pygame.draw.circle(screen,(255,0,0),(250,250),36)

def ball(x,y):
    screen.blit(ballImg,(x,y))
```

I got an error which said

```
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not pygame.Rect
```

inside the ball function. This would work if the ball was an actual image but I need it to be a shape drawn in pygame.

Comment: Does this error refer to any line in particular?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the error is inside the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pygame documentation says this about pygame.draw.circle:

```
pygame.draw.circle()
    draw a circle around a point
    circle(Surface, color, pos, radius, width=0) -> Rect
```

This means that this function *returns* a pygame rectangle. Pygame rectangles simply store a x and y coordinate and a width and height. This means that ballImg is a rectangle, not an image. It does not store any image data but rather just an area.

Your function ball blits ballImg to the screen.

```
def ball(x,y):
    screen.blit(ballImg,(x,y))
```

The pygame documentation says this about blit:

```
blit()
    draw one image onto another
    blit(source, dest, area=None, special_flags = 0) -> Rect
```

Source should be a surface and dest should be a position where the image is blit on to.

In your code, however, you try and blit a rectangle to the screen, which does not work. In fact, when you call pygame.draw.circle(), you have already drawn the circle to the screen. You do not need to blit any images to the screen at all.

If instead of blitting ballImg to the screen in ball(), you simply draw a circle at the x and y coordinates as so, your problem should be fixed:

```
def ball(x,y):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,0,0), (x, y), 36)
```